# Python Argparse Adding Text To Usage Message

Tags: python, argparse, usage-message

I am working on a small Python program that needs to get some command line parameters and use argparse to display usage message .
I have these 2 lines

```
parser.add_argument("-r",type=int,default=1)
parser.add_argument("-c",type=int,default=2)
```

And the requirement is that I show the user this message :

```
*usage: myprogram.py [-h]  [-r ROWS] [-c COLUMNS]*
```

However what I show the user is -

```
*usage: myprogram.py [-h] [-r R] [-c C]*
```

How can I turn **[-r R]** into **[-r ROW]** (and in the same manner **[-c C]** to **[-c COLUMNS]**)?

I have looked at the argsparse docs quite a bit with no avail...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [metavar parameter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#metavar):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", type=int, default=1, metavar='ROWS')
parser.add_argument("-c", type=int, default=2, metavar='COLUMNS')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then, `python test.py -h` yields

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-r ROWS] [-c COLUMNS]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -r ROWS
  -c COLUMNS
```

Comment: Yep ..that does it . Thanks a lot!